# Configure settings.py to return an html page on error

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to ask for help configuring Django's settings.py if there is a way to configure it to return an html page in case of any error, be it sending data or even misconfiguring views.

My goal is to make it return a custom page in case of error and not the default Django error page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view), you can define a custom 404.html in your root template folder.
Be aware, that if debug is true, your custom template will never be used, and your URLconf will be displayed instead.

You can also add a custom view to handle 404 errors. Add a handler to your root urls configuration like:

```
handler404 = "your.path.to.the.view.custom_404_page"
```

And then add a view to handle that 404 error:

```
def custom_404_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```